# MySQL Query Optimization for for Count Query

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, mariadb

I need help with optimization for this count query. Here are the tables:

```
activities
- activity_id (PRIMARY)
- item_id
- user_id
- created_at

INDEX: user_id_created_at (user_id, created_at)
INDEX: item_id (item_id)
```

```
retail_activities
- activity_id (PRIMARY)
- item_id
- created_at

INDEX: item_id (activity_id, item_id)
INDEX: item_id_created (activity_id, item_id, created_at)
```

```
users
- user_id (PRIMARY)
- is_private

INDEX: user_id_private (user_id, is_private)
```

## Goal

I would like to find a count of the number of items and unique users in the `retail_activities` that occurred over a date range, where the `item_id` in activities table doesn't equal the `item_id` in the retail_activities tables, and the user is not private.

Basically, I want to find the total number of retail activities that occurred and the total number of unique users who performed for a selected item_id and selected time range.

So the query would be (X is an integer, like 1234 - which is the ID if the item)

```
SELECT count(retail_activities.item_id) as total_items, count(distinct activities.user_id) as total_users 
from activities 
inner join retail_activities on retail_activities.activity_id = activities.activity_id 
inner join users on users.user_id = activities.user_id 
where users.is_private = 0 and 
activities.item_id != retail_activities.item_id and retail_activities.item_id = X and
retail_activities.created_at > "2019-11-22 00:00:00"
```

The EXPLAIN of this query is the following:

```
1   SIMPLE  retail_activities   item_id_created item_id_created 5   const   812856  Using where; Using index
1   SIMPLE  activities  eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   retail_activities.activity_id   1   Using where
1   SIMPLE  users   eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   activities.user_id  1   Using where
```

Because there is a lot of activities for this item (350k), it runs very slow (8-25s). Any way to speed this up?

Comment: This isn't the EXPLAIN for that query, What's ut_users? What's X?

Comment: @Strawberry I just updated this to remove this typo and add the explanation of X.

Comment: It is unusual to have two tables in a 1:1 relationship -- I see that they both have `PRIMARY KEY(active_id)`.  Please justify.

Comment: Or is `retail_activities` a many:many mapping table?  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; I think you have a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this query:

```
select count(*) as total_items, count(distinct a.user_id) as total_users 
from activities a join
     retail_activities ra
     on ra.activity_id = a.activity_id join
     users u
     on u.user_id = a.user_id 
where u.is_private = 0 and 
      a.item_id <> ra.item_id and
      ra.item_id = X
      ra.created_at > '2019-11-22';
```

I would recommend the following indexes:

- `retail_activities(item_id, created_at, activity_id)`
- `activities(activity_id, item_id)`  (not needed if `activity_id` is the primary key)
- `users(user_id, is_private)`

Comment: I actually had this already, just didn't document it. It still takes about 15-30s to run with this index. I updated the question.

Comment: @gregavola - The order of the columns in the index for `retail_activities` is important.

Comment: @gregavola . . . As Rick points out, the order of the columns is important.  You don't have the specified indexes.

Comment: Thanks, @RickJames - that did it. Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: @gregavola . . . How much did the speed improve?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you optimize your indexing strategy and try to use a hash index wherever you can.

According to MySQL documentation:

> As an alternative to a composite index, you can introduce a column
>   that is “hashed” based on information from other columns. If this
>   column is short, reasonably unique, and indexed, it might be faster
>   than a “wide” index on many columns.

Also, you don't need to `INDEX: item_id (activity_id, item_id)` in `retail_activities` table explicitly. That's because you have already created a composite primary key involving them. So that will act as an index as well.

And to look into index merge optimization. Here's the MySQL [journal doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/index-merge-optimization.html).
And, read up on [optimizer switch](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/optimizer-hints.html) to determine the ideal ordering of join to get the best performance. Here's some information I think you will find useful:

> Change the join order. Ways to accomplish this include join-order
>   optimizer hints (see Section 8.9.3, “Optimizer Hints”), STRAIGHT_JOIN
>   immediately following the SELECT, and the STRAIGHT_JOIN join operator.

Comment: I actually mistyped the index in that index (`INDEX: item_id (activity_id, item_id`), and updated the question. It's not a composite key, activity_id is the primary key.

Comment: Also `STRAIGHT_JOIN`, appears to make it worse - where it used another index `item_id, user_id`, which scans `375698108` rows.

Comment: The "hashed" trick is _rarely_ worth having; stick with "composite".  And "index merge intersect" is probably _always_ slower than an equivalent composite index.  Index "hints" suffer from: "They may help today, but make things worse tomorrow."